# manipulating data by column in r

Tags: r, split

I have a very large 3 column data frame with about 5000 values in each column.

Example:

```
2534  21M_BB143        G          Cluster Results for rs1816072.csv
2535  24M_BB118        G          Cluster Results for rs1816072.csv
2536  15N_BB148        G          Cluster Results for rs1816072.csv
2537  19N_BB152        G          Cluster Results for rs1816072.csv
2538    3O_Y208        G          Cluster Results for rs1816072.csv
2539    4O_Y209        G          Cluster Results for rs1816072.csv
2540    3P_Y224        G          Cluster Results for rs1816072.csv
2541    6P_Y227        G          Cluster Results for rs1816072.csv
2542  2E_Y084RE  No Call   Cluster Results for rs183961 REspots.csv
2543  4E_Y141RE        T   Cluster Results for rs183961 REspots.csv
2544  1F_Y181RE        T   Cluster Results for rs183961 REspots.csv
2545  1E_Y068RE       TC   Cluster Results for rs183961 REspots.csv
2546  3E_Y127RE       TC   Cluster Results for rs183961 REspots.csv
2547  5E_Y154RE       TC   Cluster Results for rs183961 REspots.csv
2548  6E_Y167RE        C   Cluster Results for rs183961 REspots.csv
```

I would like to group the data by the number that follows rs in the third column as well as the number that follows Y(or BB) in the first column.

There are about 40 rs numbers and 300 Y numbers.

I have tried to use split() but the problem I encounter after using split is that it is difficult to manipulate columns or rows within a split data frame. Such as using table() on one column.

I would like the output to be tables of the second column that are grouped by the number that follows rs:

```
rs1816072=
G      C    TC    No Call
35     45   42    54

rs183961=   
G      C    TC    No Call
3     75    22    54
```

Comment: Can you `dput` a sample of your data and your expected outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 <- data.frame(
   col1 = c("24M_BB118", "24M_BB118", "3O_Y208", "3O_Y208"), 
   col2 = c("G", "C", "G", "C"), 
   col3= c("Cluster Results for rs1816072.csv", "Cluster Results for rs1816072.csv", "Cluster Results for rs1816072.csv", "Cluster Results for rs1816072.csv")
   )


df1
library(stringi)
col3_extracted <- stri_match_first_regex(df1$col3, "rs(\\d+)")[,1]

lapply(split(df1$col2, col3_extracted), table)

col1_extracted <- stri_match_first_regex(df1$col1, "(Y|BB)(\\d+)")[,1]
lapply(split(df1$col2, col1_extracted), table)
```

Result:

```
$rs1816072

C G 
2 2 


$BB118

C G 
1 1 

$Y208

C G 
1 1
```

The solution extracts, using regex, "rs" and number after that or BB or Y and number after that. After that, I split column 2 using values of column 1 or 3. And when I have values from column2, which are for one value of column 3, I use `table`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd make a new column for the number following 'rs' that you'd like to group by. Let's say your data frame is named `df`, the second and third columns are named `second_col` and `third_col`, and the number after 'rs' starts in the same location in all rows:

```
library(stringr)
df$group_col <- str_sub(df$third_col, 23, 28)
```

Now, you can use the grouping function of your choice (`aggregate`, `by`, `plyr::ddply`, `dplyr::group_by` + `dplyr::summarise`, etc.). Because the grouping and value inputs are vectors, `tapply` might be appropriate:

```
tapply(df$second_col, df$group_col, sum)
```